# Use Github API to get the last commit of all repository's

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, github, github-api

I want to use the Github API for Python to be able to get every repository and check the last change to the repository.

```
import git
from git import Repo
from github import Github

repos = []

g = Github('Dextron12', 'password')
for repo in g.get_user().get_repos():
    repos.append(str(repo))

#check for last commit to repository HERE
```

This gets all repository's on my account but I want to be able to also get the last change to each one of them and I want a result like this:

```
13:46:45
```

I don't mind if it is 12 hour time either.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, the max info you can get is the SHA of the commit and the commit date:

https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Commit.html#

with your example:

```
g = Github("usar", "pass")
for repo in g.get_user().get_repos():
    master = repo.get_branch("master")
    sha_com = master.commit
    commit = repo.get_commit(sha=sha_com)
    print(commit.commit.author.date)
```

Comment: I run the above code and got an AssertionError. I am not sure what is wrong with he code but maybe a bug in the github api itself

Comment: After deleting everything on my Github page and recreating a github repository I figured out the problem was with the sha_com variable. Ill post what  I did for future reference and if others come across this problem

Answer (score 1):

```
from github import Github
from datetime import datetime

repos = {}

g = Github('username', 'password')
for repo in g.get_user().get_repos():
    master = repo.get_branch('master')
    sha_com = master.commit
    sha_com = str(sha_com).split('Commit(sha="')
    sha_com = sha_com[1].split('")')
    sha_com = sha_com[0]
    commit = repo.get_commit(sha_com)
    #get repository name
    repo = str(repo).split('Repository(full_name="Dextron12/')
    repo = repo[1].split('")')
    #CONVERT DATETIME OBJECT TO STRING
    timeObj = commit.commit.author.date
    timeStamp = timeObj.strftime("%d-%b-%Y (%H:%M:%S)")
    #ADD REPOSITORY NAME AND TIMESTAMP TO repos DICTIONARY
    repos[repo[0]] = timeStamp

print(repos)
```

I got the timeStamp by using the method Damian Lattenero suggested. upon testing his code I got a AssertationError this was because `sha_commit` was returning Commit=("sha") and not "sha". So I removed the brackets and Commit from the `sha_com` to be left with the sha all by itslef then I didn't receive that error and it worked. I then use datetime to convert the timestamp to a string and save it to a dictionary

Comment: You don't need to do the splitting of sha_com. You can just do sha_com = master.commit.sha

Answer (score 0):

@Dextron Just add .sha because its a property, No need to do split and form dictionary

```
g = Github("user", "pass")
for repo in g.get_user().get_repos():
    master = repo.get_branch("master")
    sha_com = master.commit
    commit = repo.get_commit(sha=sha_com.sha)
    print(commit.commit.author.date)
```